# The code for my aspx signup page does not work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Hello the following code for my signup page does not work. when I execute it, it refreshes and stays in the same page. But it is supposed to redirect to a page called message.aspx. The register command works as follows the person trying to register writes in comboboxs their information and then once they finished, they click the button begin which will save all their information and then use it to personalize the message.aspx page and the person will receive an email.

here is the code:

```
    Private Sub cmdRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegister.Click
    Dim status As MembershipCreateStatus
    Dim organization As New Org
    Dim employee As New Employee
    Dim description As New Description(25)
    Dim userMembership As MembershipUser
    Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder

    Try
        Membership.CreateUser( _
            txtUserName.Text, _
            txtPassword.Text, _
            txtEmail.Text, _
            "question", _
            "answer", _
            True, _
            status)

        If status.ToString = "Success" Then
            organization.GSTRate = 1
            organization.QSTRate = 1
            organization.AccountStatus = 2
            organization.Name = txtOrg.Text
            organization.Active = 1
            organization.OrgTypeID = cboType.SelectedValue
            organization.Create()
            organization = Nothing
            organization = New Org(txtOrg.Text)

            employee.Username = txtUserName.Text
            employee.OrgID = organization.ID

            employee.FirstName = txtFName.Text
            employee.LastName = txtLName.Text
            employee.Title = txtTitle.Text
            employee.Username = txtUserName.Text
            employee.IsAdmin = True
            employee.IsSupervisor = True
            employee.IsAccountant = False
            employee.IsAdvalorem = True
            employee.Email = txtEmail.Text
            employee.Phone = ""

            employee.Create()

            Roles.AddUserToRole(employee.Username, "Admin")

            userMembership = Membership.GetUser(txtUserName.Text)

            stringBuilder.Append(description.EnglishDescription)
            stringBuilder.Replace("(name)", employee.FirstName & " " & employee.LastName)
            stringBuilder.Replace("(OrgName)", organization.Name)
            stringBuilder.Replace("(username)", employee.Username)
            stringBuilder.Replace("you must activate your account", "you must <a href='https://www.advataxes.ca/login.aspx?action=activate&id=" + userMembership.ProviderUserKey.ToString + "&username=" + userMembership.UserName + "'>activate your account</a>")

            SendEmail(userMembership.Email, "Advataxes: Account created ", stringBuilder.ToString, Session("language"))
            Session("NewUserEmail") = userMembership.Email

            Response.Redirect("message.aspx?id=364")
        Else
            lblInvalidUserName.Visible = True
            If status.ToString = "DuplicateUserName" Then lblInvalidUserName.Text = "Username already exists"
        End If

    Catch ex As MembershipCreateUserException
        MsgBox(GetErrorMessage(ex.StatusCode))

    Catch ex As HttpException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        userMembership = Nothing
        organization = Nothing
        employee = Nothing
        description = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using MsgBox in an ASP.NET application?

Comment: @mason the person who made this method chose to use MsgBox. Now I am trying to make it work.

Comment: Well then you need to ditch the MsgBox. That has absolutely no business being in an ASP.NET application. Remove it from this code, and I suggest you find anywhere else it's used in the application. Think about what it does: it opens a Windows Forms MessageBox *on the machine where the code is running*. In a desktop application, that's just fine. But in a server application, that's completely inappropriate. Remove that, and put some actual error logging into your system so you can find out what's throwing an exception in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I suspect the code execution is not successfully reaching the  `Response.Redirect("message.aspx?id=364")` line and due to an exception the flow jumps to catch block/

Two possibilities I can think of:

1. Exception is thrown inside SendEmail method if smtp is not configured
2. `Membership.CreateUser` is failing due to incorrect database connectionstring

I suggest you put a breakpoint inside the `cmdRegister_Click` method and step through the code.